# Is it possible to generate binary files in AWS Lambda with the Maxmind GeoIpUpdate tool

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, maxmind

I'm currently looking to create an AWS Lambda that takes the Maxmind GeoIpUpdate tool which is an executable file and its config file and runs the executable which generates new proprietary binary files. I want to store the new files in the Lambda /tmp directory so that I can then write them to an S3 bucket.

```
        val amazonS3 = AmazonS3Client.builder().build()
        val classLoader = javaClass.classLoader
        val configFile = File(classLoader.getResource("GeoIP.conf").file)
        configFile.setWritable(true, false)
        configFile.setReadable(true, false)
        val executableFile = File(classLoader.getResource("geoipupdate").file)
        executableFile.setWritable(true, false)
        executableFile.setReadable(true, false)
        executableFile.setExecutable(true, false)
        try {
            ProcessBuilder().directory(File("/var/task/"))
                .command("./geoipupdate", "-f", "GeoIP.conf", "-d", "/tmp/").start().waitFor()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.info("error: ${e.message}")
        }
        "ls -l /tmp".runCommand()
```

When I run this code locally and write to a desktop folder it works as it intended. When I run it in AWS Lambda, I would expect that the generated files would get written to the /tmp directory so that I could then write them to an S3 bucket but after executing the command, the /tmp directory doesn't contain the files.

Comment: Lambda can run executables, however, outside of `/tmp`, the filesystem is read only, so your attempt to set the executable bit will likely fail.  What does the output of running this show in CloudWatch?

Comment: CloudWatch shows init_start runtime, start/end request id and the function call. I updated the code to copy the files to the /tmp directory before attempting to execute the file and the results are still the same. The "ls -l /tmp" command shows that the files all have the correct permissions.

Comment: Possible to write to S3 directly without through /tmp?

Comment: I ended up not using the Maxmind geoipupdate tool and instead opened a url connection with the permalink they provide and copied the input stream to a file that I can write to S3.